# How to make sql evaluate character @ in show command in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run the query in snowflake

```
show grants to user username
```

ex: `show grants to user test_account`

It works if I give username as test_account but if i change it to use something like **eax@org.net.**
It fails because of @ character.

How can I make it evaluate @ character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same way as you created them, with double quotes:

```
create user "test@account";
```

```
show grants to user "test@account";
```

Comment: I had tried that but actually it's not working. Ex: If i use "test_account" it treats it as a different object altogether because of quotes

Comment: qoutes will make it case sensitive, try `"TEST@ACCOUNT"`